# xcode 5, Mountain Lion: Very slow performance

Tags: xcode

Installed Mountain Lion and Xcode5. Tried to open a project recently developed for iOS6. And now xcode is dramatically slow. Any ideas whats wrong with him now?

EDIT

[image]

It works fast with new projects I create. It slows down only when I open the old projects.

Comment: Not sure if this question is on topic or not. At any rate, you should check your computer's resource monitor to see if it's taking up too much memory, processor time, I/O, or something else, and update the question with that information. Right now, there isn't enough information in the question to be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I found the problem. The screen attached.

[image]

When I switch 'Opens in' to Default 5, Xcode changes the UI Presentations to ugly iOS7 design and xcode suddenly starts work fast like in good old times. Switching back to 4.5 brings the very slow performance back. Thats it guys!

Comment: FWIW, on an iMac (Late 2009, Core 2 Duo 3.06 GHz) with 12 GB of RAM and Mountain Lion, I'm consistently getting over 50% User CPU usage with Xcode 5 with just one project open. Settings "Opens in" to "Default (5.0)" has no effect. Storyboard editing remains terribly slow.

Comment: Storyboardit on ihan paska. Lopetin leikkia noiden kanssa.

Answer (score 1):

It reminds a problem I had with xcode 5 ( also mountain lion), the typing was very slow..
what help to fix this was removing all breakpoints ( I had nice and big list of breakpoints)

Comment: I had no brake points at all. Old storyboards, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be keeping previous windows open too, so the more you switch between source files or XIB's, the more it will lag. I didn't check the memory use, but maybe it's running me out of RAM since I have a limited amount free with my Windows VM running. Quite annoying, but it works for me to close and reopen Xcode when this starts happening.